# Secure Mobile backend

Tags: api, security, mobile, backend

I am building a backend for a mobile application. the application contains funds, fund management and transfer. The backend has to be highly secure. what are the best practices for building secure backend a APIs. How does the banks do it for their mobile apps ?. 
I have experience with web development but new to this are of security.

Comment: This has nothing to do with iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ideas:

- Use an HTTPS API Gateway
- Generate client-side SSL certificate and make the public key
  available to your clients
- Set your API methods to require authorization (JWT, OAuth)
- Use API keys
- Set API rate limits
- Use secure cloud-hosted microservices